# Documentation of Application settings with SHFB

Tags: c#, sandcastle, shfb

I am trying to document the settings of my application in a Windows help file using Sandcastle Help File Builder.
 I have documented the settings in Visual Studio using Settings - Properties-Definition.
I can see inside the generated Settings.Designer.cs file my description in the

> [global::System.Configuration.SettingsDescriptionAttribute("description")]

Is there a way to extract this with Sandcastle or should I use a different approach?
I can see the data in the generated xml from the build process. I have set all Visibility to true, but can still not see the Settings anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandcastle ignores code with the CompilerGenerated Attribute. Unfortunately there is not setting to fix this.